# How do I use MSHTML on a machine that does not have Visual Studio installed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, iis-6, mshtml

I am using mshtml to parse HTML in my ASP.NET-MVC application.  Works great on my development machine, which has VS2008 Professional installed.  Works great on my staging machine, which has VS Express 2008/WebDev installed.  But it throws a FileNotFoundException when trying to load the COM object on the production server, which has no versions of Visual Studio.

> ```
> Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
>     Exception message: Could not load file or assembly
> ```
>
> 'Microsoft.mshtml, Version=7.0.3300.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

I don't want to install Visual Studio on the production box.  I have read a [suggestion](http://bytes.com/groups/net-vb/425451-assembly-reference-problem) that running C:\Program files\Common Files\Merge
modules\vs_piaredist.exe solves this problem but this directory does not exist on my production box.  How can I use mshtml on the production machine?

Comment: vs_piaredist.exe does not exist on the staging or dev machines either, but there is a file called vs90_piaredist on the dev machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vs90_piaredist from the dev machine seems to be the solution.  The interop assembly is called Microsoft.mshtml.dll and it lives at C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies.  Running vs90_piaredist created this directory on the production machine, and placed 5 interop dlls in there, including Microsoft.mshtml.dll.

This [thread](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/2007-06/msg00127.html) had some good discussion on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't mshtml IE dependent? What version of IE is installed on the production box?  Consider upgrading to atleast 6

Comment: IE7.  The mshtml.dll is sitting in the system32 dir, but for whatever reason, the application cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

IE is unmanaged code so there needs to be a interop layer to go from managed to unmanaged. The [Primary Interop Assembly](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faax7sdch.aspx&ei=zkEUSvrHAo2KtAPE--zhDQ&usg=AFQjCNHL-MW34fCk8dGvsIi7PzIpl8ZNrg&sig2=wWCN_3ND6aKrMwNR-Ao6fw) (PIA) is one that is usually shipped by the vendor. This is why you're being suggested to run the piaredist.exe